# Identify book about fighting tournament with the opponent wearing gold armor, plus rulers being mind-controlled by tentacled being

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to find a book I read in the late eighties but I can't remember the name of it at all.

The plot centered around a man coming to a fighting tournament. He wears a sort of gray/silver jumpsuit. The main antagonist is wearing gold armor but is very fragile and weedy inside the huge armor (blue/gray skin tone). The front cover depicted both of these men along with a group of people watching who were the rulers of the planet. It turns out that these are in the grip of a tentacled being who is controlling them with a tentacle in each member's mind. I think he had a companion who had wings (could have been an angel or the name of the lady was angel).

Can anyone suggest what this book could be?

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/47022/series-of-young-adult-science-fiction-books-from-early-1980s-about-last-of-a-rac (about the series as a whole)

Answer (score 14):

Sounds like Day of the Starwind, one of the Keill Randor [Last Legionary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_Legionary) series by Douglas Hill. The companions name was Glr, a telepathic avian. The book you are referring to is probably **Planet of the Warlord**, this cover match your description.

[image: Planet of the Warlord]

Comment: Read these books when I was a kid and loved them, wonder if I get them on Kindle now?

Comment: I added the book cover and the Title of the book he was referring to. I found the cover [here](http://www.thecoolbooklounge.com/authors/3586/)

Comment: Good grief that was fast! That does look a lot like it I think they may have changed the cover slightly or my memory is failing (the latter more than likely ;) ) Thank you!

Comment: [link](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/customer-media/product-gallery/0330267132) is the cover I remember thanks again!

Comment: @WesWakeman You should mark this as the answer if it was :)

Comment: @WesWakeman: Jan is right - please accept the answer to make Phil's day. :)

Comment: @Wikis If only it was that simple... :-)