# Spaceship crashes, octopus monster creates false reality

Tags: story-identification

A spaceship crashes onto a water planet, an octopus type creature hooks onto the passengers and creates a false reality for them. Most of the passengers actually died. It was from so long ago, and that's all I remember

Comment: Is that *everything*? Currently this seems like too little to go on. Can you add anything at all? What language did you read it in? What country? How long ago? Any idea about the cover? Anything else about the plot?

Comment: It also sounds a bit like the _Red Dwarf_ episode [_Back to Reality_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back_to_Reality_%28Red_Dwarf%29), where the creature creates a reality so depressing that people commit suicide after a while.

Comment: Was this something you watched, listened to or read?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A vague description, but it sounds like one of the plot points in [*The Ellimist Chronicles*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/363351.The_Ellimist_Chronicles) in the *Animorphs* series by K. A. Applegate.

> A spaceship crashes onto a water planet

A group of survivors from a planet called Ketra (which is destroyed by invading aliens) crashland on an aquatic moon. This includes the protagonist, who is known both as Toomin and his gaming nickname Ellimist.

> an octopus type creature hooks onto the passengers and creates a false reality for them. Most of the passengers actually died.

A gigantic, many-tentacled sea creature known as "Father" absorbs the minds of the Ketrans, killing everyone but Toomin. Father keeps Toomin alive while telepathically communicating with him in a sort of false reality, using the minds of his dead friends to talk to him.

> It was from so long ago, and that's all I remember

*The Ellimist Chronicles* was released in 2000. A lot of other stuff also happens in the novel, obviously; I wrote [another answer covering the book here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/150373/book-about-a-spacefaring-race-of-winged-creatures-with-talons-read-about-15-yea/154390#154390), see if any of the rest of the plot sounds familiar. Here's the cover:

[image]

Comment: You are the bomb dot com. My life was incomplete without you thank you so much for helping me 

Answer (score 3):

This sounds a lot like Michael Crichton's "Sphere". Scientists uncover an alien vessel that crashed into the ocean ages ago and investigate it, building an underwater facility. After entering the ship, some of the crew's thoughts begin to manifest in reality. One crew member who had just read 20,000 leagues under the sea, was convinced that a squid would attack them, and soon enough, an intelligent squid soon does.
It becomes unclear what is real and most of the crew dies, this is as far as I remember.

I apologize for poor answer formatting, I'm used to a desktop but stuck with mobile temporarily