# Book (pre 1982) - recalled mercenary only survivor of radiation weapon

Tags: story-identification, science

I read a book somewhere around 1981 or 82 at our local library. It was the first book in a series. I can almost remember the entire book just not the title nor the author.  I would love to find out if the author continued the series.

It starts out that there is a planet of mercenaries who hire out their services to other planets. There is a planetary distress call which recalls all the warriors back to the home planet. One warrior whose starship malfunctions, is left in orbit as the rest of the warriors enter the planets atmosphere and are immediately killed by a extremely lethal radiation weapon that has killed the entire planet.

He was close enough to the planet to become terminally ill, and ends up going out into the universe seeking who sent the bomb in the grain supply and killed his people and to try and find another warrior.  On the way, he meets up with a scientist who knows what is going on. They replace his bones through some process to keep him alive.

There is also a creature that reminded me of a ghost. That is all that I remember.

Comment: This comes up about once a month here.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/47022

Answer (score 8):

I believe you are talking about the series called "[The Last Legionary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_Legionary)" by Douglas Hill.

This is a series of 5 books depicting the last survivor of a planet of mercenaries. The first book is his young life, which is actually a prequel written after the others. In the first book (Not the prequel), the protagonist (Keill Randor) is recalled to his homeworld which is under attack, and he finds it covered in radiation. He receives a message from his childhood friend warning him off, but it is too late.

The rest of the books/descriptions match yours.

The 5 books are:

1. Young Legionary (1982)
2. Galactic Warlord (1979)
3. Deathwing over Veynaa (1980)
4. Day of the Starwind (1980)
5. Planet of the Warlord (1981)