# Space opera featuring gladiatorial combat with an enhanced main character

Tags: story-identification, books, space-opera, gladiator

I’m looking for a book I last read in the late 1970s to early 1980s. The main character was a young male humanoid whose skeleton had been enhanced with titanium to increase its lightness and strength. I think this character ended up leading some sort of battle against a rival faction or planet.

Comment: Suggested close as duplicate of [series of young adult science fiction books from early 1980s about last of a race of martial experts that sees the destruction of his home planet](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/47022/series-of-young-adult-science-fiction-books-from-early-1980s-about-last-of-a-rac)

Comment: Might be better to wait till the OP has a chance to identify it as a match or not.

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron see confirmation comment on the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like *[The Last Legionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_Legionary)* series, which would make this question a duplicate of [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/234287/20490) and [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/47022/20490) and [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/65329/20490) and [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/67493/20490).

The hero does have a metal skeleton:

> The Overseers also explain that, since the radiation sickness had
> settled into his bones, they were forced to replace his entire
> skeleton—using an unbreakable alloy—effectively rendering Keill's
> bones unbreakable.

And the series follows his battle against the criminal syndicate that destroyed his homeworld.

Comment: Arg.  I _had_ to go look up which book Kiell competed in a combat tournament instead of posting right away. :-P  That book is [*Planet of the Warlord*](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?12849) for what it's worth.

Comment: @DavidW, when this question comes up again next month you can beat me to it :)

Comment: Thanks. Much appreciated. Sorry for the duplicate question!

Comment: @APS No worries on the dupe, means it's a popular question.  However, it helps us close this as a dupe - just bookkeeping - if you click the check box to Accept this answer.