# Earth destroyed, survivor grows up on alien world, later joins Earth military

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

I'm looking for a book that I read years ago.

It's similar to the Starwolf's series by Edmond Hamilton but much closer to the 60's/70's (not sure of the exact date).

In the story an alien force has destroyed Earth. The few Earthmen who survived are given a planet to live on. A human ends up on an alien world. He eventually grows up and fights earthmen as a member of the aliens forces.

After breaking free of the aliens, he joins the Earth military and is a very good fighter pilot. When a major (Final) battle takes place and he's part of the force on the Earth side. During the battle the aliens try to use mental control to bring him back but he manages to break free and help end the battle.

There are vague parts I'm having a problem really remembering, the main part being how the teams are set up.  think they use a family connection in some way.
I remember the title as being "Starwolf's" but I've never been able to find anything.

Thanks so much for any help I can get.

Comment: Do you remember any other details that might be helpful? What did the aliens look like? Did they do anything unusual? How did the survivors survive when the Earth was destroyed? How was the Earth "destroyed"? Is it completely obliterated or has just human civilization been wiped out? How and when does the protagonist first encounter the "other" earthmen? Is there anything special about them?

Comment: Sounds awfully close to Empire (In Her Name), but that was released in 2009.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/47022/series-of-young-adult-science-fiction-books-from-early-1980s-about-last-of-a-rac

Answer (score 1):

The **[Last Legionary series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_Legionary)** by Douglas Hill.

The books tell of the adventures of Keill Randor, the last survivor of his planet's population, who are annihilated at the beginning of the book Galactic Warlord. Randor's people were hardened over generations by their inhospitable planet, and become interstellar mercenaries.

In the last book the evil Warlord uses his dreaded Arachnis technological device to mentally enslave Our Hero, but later he breaks free.