# 1980s/90s science fiction book. Hero gets trapped in high tech straightjacket

Tags: story-identification

The book is about a man who carries a secret that some other beings want, so they are looking to capture him. They catch up with him at one stage and put a straightjacket-like contraption on him which gets tighter the more he moves so he deliberately moves so that he can make them think it has malfunctioned so they will take it off. I'm sure there was more than one book in the series. I read this in the late 1980s to 1990. It's sort of along the same lines as the Dumarest series by E. C. Tubb but is slightly different.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/47022/series-of-young-adult-science-fiction-books-from-early-1980s-about-last-of-a-rac

Answer (score 5):

This sounds somewhat like one of the Last Legionary quartet stories by Douglas Hill.  In the final book of the series "Planet of the Warlord", Kiell Randor (the protagonist) allows himself to be captured and his captors place him in a straitjacket that will tighten if the wearer moves.

Extracts from the book are on Google Books [Planet of the Warlord](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=I3HVCQAAQBAJ&pg=PT16&lpg=PT16&dq=kiell%20randor%20strait%20jacket&source=bl&ots=ed_ced9cAs&sig=xRBddpsy4UjZtQ4Zd5BMnPmUs_Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjkhuqVmbXRAhUKJMAKHfoPBPkQ6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=kiell%20randor%20strait%20jacket&f=false).
From memory the books were published in the early 80's and an omnibus (which I've still got :)) was published a little later in that decade or early 90's.

I read them in school, and loved them, and still enjoy reading the series when I come back to it.